# Word.Application is not defined in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word

I am trying to to automate Microsoft Word by using Visual Studio to print an existing document with parameters

I am using this as reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-create-file-using-visual-basic

But after following the steps and adding 'Microsoft Office  16.0 Object Library' in my project's reference, it says the Word.Application is not defined.

I've looked it up and the results I found is the same method but in different programming languages.

Please help me.

Comment: Given that the C# version of this article references "Microsoft Visual C# 2005 or Microsoft Visual C# .NET." I'd look for something a bit more up to date to work from.

Comment: The VB (not VB.Net) version is also Copyright 2001.

Comment: The web page you linked to says to reference the Microsoft *Word* Object Library, not the Microsoft Office Object Library. the two are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you need to make sure you have a reference to the Office applications you are using. They are version specific and if you want your solution to run on multiple versions, you have to include the earliest version your solution supports.

[image]

In the main module of your solution you have to Import the application library.

[image]

Then you need to declare a variable that will be your reference to the Office application and assign it.

```
Public wApp As Word.Application
wApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
```

And from there you can reference the various application methods.

```
If wApp.Options.DefaultFilePath(Word.WdDefaultFilePath.wdDocumentsPath) = Nothing Then
            wApp.Options.DefaultFilePath(Word.WdDefaultFilePath.wdDocumentsPath) = zPath
    End If
```